# Reaplce img value with value from list Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I create txt file with 4 values and save them into list [] , my problem is to replace src links in localy saved html file with values from list , but program replace only last value from list.

Program Code:

```
 list= []
 num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('txt.txt'))
 with open("txt.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        list.append(line)

 s = open("index.html").read()
 i=0
 for i,val in enumerate(list):
  word = ''
  html = re.sub('src="(.*?)"', 'src="'+word.join(val)+'"',s,count=num_lines)
 f = open("index2.html",'w')
 f.write(html)
 f.close
```

Txt File:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

Html result :

```
<html>

<body>
<a href="http://simple_site"/>
<img src="value4">

<a href="http://simple_site"/>
<img src="value4">

<a href="http://simple_site"/>
<img src="value4">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The last replacement you do overwrites the previous replacements.

Comment: then how to fix it?

Comment: You have 3 image tags and 4 values in the list, which value should go to which image? Maybe you can wrap your images in divs of unique ids and construct more specific regex for each image?